# A set of integers related to $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, pi

Let $\Psi$ be the maps
\begin{array}{lrcl}
\Psi : & {\mathbb N}^{(\mathbb N)} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R^+\cup\{+\infty\} \\
    & A=(a_i)_{i\in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}} & \longmapsto & \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R^+} \displaystyle\frac{16x^2}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^{2i}}}\text d x. \end{array}

We denote by $\mathfrak P$ the subset of ${\mathbb N}^{(\mathbb N)}$ so that $$\forall A\in \mathfrak P \quad \Psi(A)=\pi.$$

We know that $\mathfrak P\ne \emptyset$, because $\Psi((1,6,35,15,6,1))=\pi$.

What else can be said about $\mathfrak P$ ?

Is there a way to characterize all elements of $\mathfrak P$ ?

Is there any interesting necessary or sufficient conditions to be in $\mathfrak P$ ?

Does $\mathfrak P$ admits elements of any lengths (big enough) ?

Is $\mathfrak P$ even infinite ?

Is there any palindromes in $\mathfrak P$ ?

Comment: I understand the interest in all the questions you pose, but why on earth would you like to know if there is a palindrome in $\mathfrak{P}$?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Just ouf of curiosity.

Comment: Ok. Well, $1$ and $6$ technically are palyndromes ;)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Yes, but we don't have $\Psi(1)$ or $\Psi(6)$ equal $\pi$ unfortunately...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I kinda misread the question there ^^